# Arquillian: Wildfly embedded?

Tags: junit, jboss, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

Until now I had my integration tests running with Arquillian and an embedded Glassfish 4.x. As I suffer from bug [ARQ-1458](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-1458), I tried migrating to Wildfly 8.0.0.Beta1.

My deps in Maven are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0.Beta1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0.Beta1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When running my test, I get the error that jbossHome is null. I have NO arquillian.xml. When checking Github sources for wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded (POM), I wonder WHY an embedded container requires JBOSS_HOME? I understand to have it for the managed and remote variants, but why do I need it for an embedded one?
The Arquillian pages also only have examples for JBoss AS as managed servers, so I wonder it it is possible at all (but why is there wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded then?)?

Or should I stick to a managed container with using the maven-dependency-plugin to download the container (see http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/#add_more_containers - bottom)?

Thanks and best regards!

Exact error is:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.ConfigurationException: jbossHome 'null' must exist
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.deployment.Validate.configurationDirectoryExists(Validate.java:139)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.embedded.EmbeddedContainerConfiguration.validate(EmbeddedContainerConfiguration.java:102)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.createDeployableConfiguration(ContainerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.setup(ContainerImpl.java:181)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$7.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:149)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$7.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.setupContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$1.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$1.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:55)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:209)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.setupContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
```

Comment: I have the feeling, that wildfly-embedded is not really an embedded container or not yet finished. Because I did some digging and had a look at the "EmbeddedContainerConfiguration" java class. There they explicity check for jbossHome, moduleHome and bundleHome. Therefore you have to download a "real" wildfly, which in my opinion is not an embedded-container ;) I am currently using the managed/remote adapter instead and everything works just fine. For the embedded tests I will use glassfish-embedded :)

Comment: Yepp, saw the same code :( So I am afraid I have to go for the same option and wait for the fox of ARQ-1458. I am not giving up, cos using an embedded Wildfly would by my first option, so that one can checkout the project and do a Maven Build w/o having to install manyally or use other help of plugins or ANT tasks.

Comment: I know this thread is pretty old but I would appreciate if anyone could let me know what did you people finally conclude about this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess that it works differently w/ Wildfly than with Glassfish:

https://community.jboss.org/thread/236562

:(

Edit: [Docker](http://docker.io) adds another perspective on this issue. I could easily manage the external container using Docker and Maven while still using Arquillian. Did not test it yet, but if someone stumbles upon this...

Comment: Thats true, but personally I would prefer remote (or managed) adapter, as it gives us more accurate test results (and less problems also).

Answer (score 8):

One should set environment variable JBOSS_HOME to path to jBoss installation. Otherwise, a tag **property** should be added to arquillian.xml inside a container tag.

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">


<container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">/path/to/jboss/as</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

from example application jboss-javaee6-webapp

Answer (score 5):

use systemPropertyVariables

```
<profile>
<id>INTEGRATION_TESTS</id>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- this is the wildfly emb.container - BUT eventually it is not a fully blown emb.container-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jdbc</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                        <name>ojdbc6.jar</name>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>datasource</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <address>subsystem=datasources,data-source=tests</address>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <properties>
                                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@***:1521:xe</connection-url>
                                    <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/tests</jndi-name>
                                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                                    <enable>true</enable>
                                    <user-name>***</user-name>
                                    <password>***</password>
                                    <driver-name>ojdbc6.jar</driver-name>
                                    <use-ccm>false</use-ccm>
                                </properties>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <jboss.home>${project.basedir}/target/wildfly-8.2.0.Final</jboss.home>
                    <module.path>${project.basedir}/target/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/modules</module.path>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>

</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this nice article](http://arquillian.org/blog/2012/04/13/the-danger-of-embedded-containers/) written by Dan Allen.

To be short: generally do not use an embedded container (glassfish with EclipseLink particularly). Standalone server gives us more accurate test results.

Also I prefer remote adapters due to **speed of development** (none server startup with every test launch, just start it manually once).
If you want the container to start automatically like with embedded, then switch to a managed container.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Grzesiek,

thank you very much for that informative and important link. I think I will change to remote container thus, especially because weaving is an important thing for me.

The original (and still valid, to some point) idea was that someone can just download a Maven project and just run the unit/integration tests w/o installing a container.

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: @TimoBoewing You are welcome:] I understand you well, because once I've also been trapped by this tempting idea.