# how to use arquillian for integration tests having multi maven modules

Tags: testing, module, structure, containers, jboss-arquillian

I have multiple maven modules: DBLayer (Contains all entities),UserManagement (User management services), WebApp

For setting up the testing i need to understand how to structure everything.

I want to test each module in an embedded container. As you all know, in each module I have my test folder where I put my test classes. Do I have to put the ShrinkWrap setup in each module test class (code that prepares embedded container for testing), or is that only needed in the webapp?

I also have the arquillian dependencies in each module pom file. Is there a better way to add these dependencies?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to test each module in an embedded container (...)

If you are considering an embedded container, please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25911594/1037316). Dan Allen explains it in details in his short article [The Danger of Embedded Containers](http://arquillian.org/blog/2012/04/13/the-danger-of-embedded-containers/). Please take a look at it.

It looks to me that you are using Maven, then the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25908693/1037316) you may find useful in terms of separating integration tests from unit tests. To be short: stick to the Maven naming conventions (just name your integration tests with `*IT` suffix, e.g. `MyClassIT.java`) and let `maven-failsafe-plugin` do its job.

---

> Do I have to put the ShrinkWrap setup in each module test class (code
>   that prepares embedded container for testing), or is that only needed
>   in the webapp?

Unfortunately yes. That is because you may want to prepare a different deployment for each test class. But drawbacks are clear:

1. Usually repeated deployment's setup.
2. Slowed down execution of tests (there is a new deploy operation for every test case)

**Fortunately**, there is [Arquillian Suite Extension](https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension) that lets you achive that. The Extension will force all classes in a TestSuite to run from the same `DeploymentScenario`. But as far as I know, it is more complex topic than it would appear on the surface - just keep in mind that this extension (although extremely useful) may not work with some other arquillian extensions.

---

> I also have the arquillian dependencies in each module pom file. Is
>   there a better way to add these dependencies?

Your intuition is correct:) Yes, there are better ways. Personally I would recommend keep dependency to the **arquillian** only in a parent `pom.xml` file, then all sub-modules would inherit this dependency.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Generally, be sure to read [Getting started with Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/) Guide.