# Unable to Inject EntityManager in JPA Integration Testing With Arquillian and WildFly

Tags: maven, jpa, integration-testing, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying do integration testing with the following stack:

```
App server: Embedded WildFly
CDI container: Weld
Database: In-memory H2
ORM: Hibernate/JPA
Platform: Java 8
OS: Mac OS X 10.10
```

I've setup basic integration testing with Arquillian (as done [here](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/)) and I'm able to inject dependencies but injecting `EntityManager` proves to be a challenge. Dereferencing the entity manager field always results in a `NullPointerException`.

I've seen many articles (including [this](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/) and [this](https://developer.jboss.org/en/arquillian/blog/2010/10/04/the-perfect-recipe-for-testing-jpa-2-revisited)) but I'm still not able to get this seemingly simple thing to work.

Please see below my `pom.xml`

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit Container Implementation for the Arquillian Project -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-persistence-dbunit</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Alpha7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

test-persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.xyz.hellomaven.DummyEntity</class>

    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
    <!--<jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>-->
    <!--<jta-data-source>jdbc/arquillian</jta-data-source>-->

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <!--<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />-->
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Test case

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GreeterTest {

  @Inject
  private Greeter instance; // Injection works!

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em; // Null pointer.

  public GreeterTest() {
  }

  @Deployment
  public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
        .addClasses(Greeter.class, PhraseBuilder.class, DummyInterceptor.class)
        .addAsResource("logging.properties", "META-INF/logging.properties")
        .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
        .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
  }

  @Test
  public void testCreateGreeting() {
    System.out.println("createGreeting");
    assertEquals("Hello, Steve!", instance.createGreeting("Steve"));
  }

  @Test
  public void testPersistence() {
    DummyEntity de = new DummyEntity();
    de.setId(1l);
    de.setName("Petr Cech");
    de.setAge(10);
    em.persist(de);

    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT d.age FROM DummyEntity d");
    assertEquals(10, q.getResultList().get(0));
  }
}
```

Complete Maven project available [on GitHub](https://github.com/oluwasayo/MavenArquillianDemo).

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not knowledgeable with Arquillian, but container managed entitymagner is only available on the server. I believe you will have to use the application managed entitymanager.

Comment: There are two issues with this.
1. It wouldn't work. If you're unable to inject an EM, you won't be able to inject an EMF (kindly correct me if I'm wrong).
2. Even if it did work, this makes my "integration test" a lot less solid as the architecture is no longer the same as that of the production environment (container vs bean managed persistence/transaction)

Arquillian is an integration testing environment and is expected to produce supporting server components. This isn't the same as working solely in JUnit/TestNG which would be a SE-like application.

Answer (score 1):

just don't use weld, sins data-sources is out of things that could be covered by CI and DI. probably you may mock it with Mokito and stay with light Weld,

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But if you want to deal with real DB use managed jboss (ExampleDS is a demo jboss h2 datasource) or managed glassfish instead.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

ref. https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-examples/blob/master/arquillian-persistence-tutorial/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Soloviev Dmitry, you use a CDI container for your integration test, which only enables CDI.

There are two options I see:

**First one** is to use a wildfly-embedded container configured in your maven project, so during maven phase running your integration-tests, wildfly will be downloaded and your test package will be deployed to it. So with ExampleDS it would work fine, as it comes with Wildfly out of the box.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895332/arquillian-wildfly-embedded) for details

**Second one** would consist in not using Arquillian for your integration test. So if your integration test only covers managed beans, (not session beans, Wildfly specific resources, ...), you could just instantiate a CDI container prior to your test execution (in @Before or @BeforeClass annotated method using Junit for example) and then instantiate your EntityManager by using the EntityManagerFactory class, referencing your persistence unit used for this integration test. With this method, you could also create CDI producers to inject other resources for your integration test, mocks, depending on the scope of your test.

***maven dependency***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

***The test class***

```
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer;
import org.junit.*;

public class ExampleIT {

    private EntityManager em;

    protected static Weld weld;
    protected static WeldContainer container;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        weld = new Weld();
        container = weld.initialize();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void close() {
        weld.shutdown();
    }

    @Before
    private void before(){
    em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPersistenceUnit").createEntityManager();
    }

    @Test
    public void testToto(){
        // Do something with entity manager ...
    }

}
```

I usually opt for second solution for Integration tests, because it's easier to setup than Arquillian tests, and faster to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Use the application managed entitymanager.

```
@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

and create entityManager using

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

a container managed entitymanager is created and injected by container itself. If you are not under a server environment, then you need to use  [application managed persistence context](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbra/index.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time to attempt to help me.

I just tried this approach (just to be sure) and unsurprisingly, it didn't work.

There are two issues with this.
1. It wouldn't work. If you're unable to inject an EM, you won't be able to inject an EMF (kindly correct me if I'm wrong).
2. Even if it did work, it makes my "integration test" a lot less solid as the architecture is no longer the same as that of the production environment (container vs bean managed persistence/transaction)

Arquillian is an integration testing environment and is expected to produce supporting server components.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the transaction manager + Entity Manger Factory are missing in your context file. Configure both in test-persistence.xml, then make the entity manager factory a property of the transaction manager.

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for taking time out of your schedule to help me with an answer. Could you kindly provide example snippets for implementing your solution? Thanks in advance.